# SupportMapFragment returning null [Android Studio] [kotlin]

Tags: android, kotlin, google-maps

im trying to fallow the google maps api guide on displaying a map in a fragment. But every time i call the support fragment manager it just keeps returning null to me. I don't know what im doing wrong and i thought my code was the same as the example.

.
fragment:

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

MainActivity

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), OnMapReadyCallback {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val mapFragment = supportFragmentManager      // right here keeps returning null
                 .findFragmentById(R.id.map) as SupportMapFragment
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this)
```

im sorry if this question is strange. im literally just figuring it out for the first time

Answer (score 0):

Try once

```
val mapFragment = supportFragmentManager
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map) as SupportMapFragment?
            mapFragment!!.getMapAsync(this)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define the `OnMapReadyCallback` on the top of the file as follows:

```
private val callback = OnMapReadyCallback { googleMap ->
        //do your stuff
}
```

and in `onViewCreated()` :

```
  override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        val mapFragment = childFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.map) as SupportMapFragment?
        mapFragment?.getMapAsync(callback)
```